# Problem with raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator, error-000539

When working with raster calculator there is an error 000539? The program failed to create a common raster map. I don't know what to do. I did the same in school without any problems. But now, on my computer the raster calculator will not make a map.

Comment: Could you post your raster math expression?

Comment: http://failiem.lv/u/xkzobqd

Comment: The link has rotted, so this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

Error 000539 means you have an error in your expression.

This [thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/54081-Raster-Calculator-error-using-AND-OR) addresses a similar issue. This [ArcGIS help document](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Working_with_operators/00p600000008000000/) should help you better understand expression syntax.

If you post the expression you used in the Raster Calculator someone may be able to evaluate it for you.

Comment: I counted to raster files. For example: "kudrras" + "kaliezras" in raster calculator

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your Raster Calculator window before you run the tool? It would be useful to see your inputs.

Comment: http://failiem.lv/u/xkzobqd

Comment: can you give us a screenshot of both rasters and also the table of attributes?

Comment: You mean atribute tables of all raster files?

Comment: Problem is solved. Python-2.6.5.msi was mising in the folder. I install and Raster Calculator works